# Apple iPhone won't connect to insecure website

Tags: iphone, safari, error, certificate

A certificate is expired of an application of ours and a client still wants to access it. He is using an Apple iPhone and gets the message

`Safari cannot open the page because it could not establish a secure connection to the server`

There is no link or button like on desktop to ignore and proceed. Is there a way to ignore the message and proceed?

[image: iPhone screenshot]

Comment: Does connecting over port 80 help? You also will want to know exactly which version of iOS is in play.

Comment: Instead of finding a way to work around a security measure, wouldn‘t it be easier to replace the certificate?

Comment: @nohillside Faster then clicking a link to bypass the warning message in a browser?? Certificate is fine, just the signature is expired and we are not going to update the certificate because the domain will be dropped.

Comment: Teaching users to work around security measures is a bad idea, on the long run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the certificate has expired, but HSTS is enabled, it is not possible to bypass the error message ‘Safari cannot open the page because it could not establish a secure connection to the server’.

---

To bypass an expired certificate for a site without HSTS, choose Show Details, then ‘visit this website’.

[image]
[image]

If the certificate is was revoked, a similar error message is shown but it cannot be bypassed.

Comment: I feel they are different errors

Comment: @ankiiiiiii Then I suppose the situation is more complicated than a certificate expiration. I guess HSTS is involved, in which case the error cannot be bypassed. I’ve edited my answer, thanks

Comment: @grg The app had a bought signed certificate, which is just expired. Every other browser can just ignore the message and proceed. The problem is that Safari on iPhone doesn't have the link to bypass. I updated the question with screenshot of the error.

Comment: @Sven Try https://expired.badssl.com which is a test domain serving an expired certificate and see if you get the error message from your screenshot or the error message from my screenshot which includes the bypass link.

Comment: @grg Asked the client to navigate to the expired url and he got the same result as your screenshot. So you're right, the webserver has HSTS enabled. Thanks for your answer and time.